# Print Multiple Substrings Including an IP Address

Tags: awk, sed, grep, string

Good day!

I have a giant input file that displays a lot of garbage and I would like to export multiple substrings. The problem is that sometimes additional information is injected into the file making the data that I want jump around in the string. The only good thing is that the IP address is always first.
Is there any way to accomplish this using either grep, sed, or awk?

```
**Input file:**
Garbage ABC=10.100.100.100 Trash Unwanted DEF=1020 Crap
NotNeeded Disgard ABC=192.168.0.1 DEF=91 Garbage Trash
ABC=10.110.110.110 Garbage Trash NA Remove DEF=441
Garbage Crap Discard NotNeeded Trash
Unwanted Trash ABC=192.168.1.1 Unwanted DEF=12000 Nothing

**Desired output:**
ABC=10.100.100.100 DEF=1020
ABC=192.168.0.1 DEF=91
ABC=10.110.110.110 DEF=441
ABC=ABC=192.168.1.1 DEF=12000
```

Thank you in advance for any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: Do you **really** mean "export" or do you just mean "print"?

Comment: You're right, I should update the title of the question. Maybe this is why I didn't find anything of value when I was searching around for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: You can do that by clicking the `edit` button under your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `awk` you can use `FPAT` to define the fields you want to match using a regular expression:

```
awk -v FPAT='[A-Z]+=[0-9.]+' '
  { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", $i (i==NF ? ORS : OFS) }
' file
```

- `[A-Z]+` match one or more characters within A-Z
- `=` match a literal `=`
- `[0-9.]+` match one or more digits and dots

This loops over the matched fields and prints each field using a space character (`OFS`) as separator. Only the last field `NF` is separated by a newline (`ORS`).

Output:

```
ABC=10.100.100.100 DEF=1020
ABC=192.168.0.1 DEF=91
ABC=10.110.110.110 DEF=441
ABC=192.168.1.1 DEF=12000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent. Instead of [A-Z] I'd like to be more specific. How can I tell it to do both and only ABC= and DEF= values?

Comment: Change `FPAT` to `'(ABC|DEF)=[0-9.]+'`.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you. It works perfectly now. In all of my searches I never saw FPAT.